# Time Machine: tmutil compare gives always 0B as result

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, terminal.app

i had several time machine backups. The most recent drive failed. I wanted to compare an older backup to my current Mac OS internal drive.

Usually, you would use

`sudo tmutil compare`

however it gives the error

```
Unable to locate machine directory for host.

-------------------------------------
Added:         0B
Removed:       0B
Changed:       0B
```

If I provide the folder for comparison (the most recent backup):

`sudo tmutil compare "/Volumes/Time\ Machine\ 1/Backups.backupdb/MyComputer/2020-07-24-170724"`

There is no error nor a result:

```
-------------------------------------
Added:         0B
Removed:       0B
Changed:       0B
```

I can guarantee that there was change since the last backup. The result can not be null.

I assume that by providing the path, tmutil compares the path to itself (therefore no change).

The solution might be to provide the "machine directory for host" as it was asked in the first error message.

If the "machine directory for host" is not the path to the most recent backup, what is the host?

I also tried to use the path to my internal drive:

`sudo tmutil compare "/"`

which gives the error:

```
Must specify a snapshot root when performing a machine comparison.
Usage: tmutil compare [-@acdefghlmnstuEX] [-D depth] [-I name]
       tmutil compare [-@acdefghlmnstuEX] [-D depth] [-I name] snapshot_path
       tmutil compare [-@acdefghlmnstuEUX] [-D depth] [-I name] path1 path2
```

Btw, usually the Mac OS recognizes the external hard drive as time machine and changes the icon on the desktop. This is currently not the case.

Furthermore, i couln't find any help at the documentation:

https://ss64.com/mac/tmutil.html

Is there any other documentation?

OS: 10.12.6 (Sierra)

Edit:

Even if I provide 2 paths (two old backups), they give zero change as result:

```
sudo tmutil compare "/Volumes/Time\ Machine\ 1/Backups.backupdb/MyComputer/2020-07-24-170724" "/Volumes/Time\ Machine\ 1/Backups.backupdb/MyComputer/2019-02-25-111629"

-------------------------------------
Added:         0B
Removed:       0B
Changed:       0B
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself:

1. Make time machine backup with the current drive
2. navigate to the folder of backup

   cd /Volumes/Time\ Machine\ 1/Backups.backupdb/MyComputer
3. compare the backups with this command:

   sudo tmutil compare 2020-07-29-154121 2020-07-24-170724 > ~/Desktop/result.txt

Alternative: Sometimes you can just start the backup and stop it while it is still preparing, which somehow fixes the problem.

I don't know why this is the solution. I found this post, which is basically what i did as solution:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232695/find-differences-between-time-machine-backups

Has anyone an idea, why this worked finally?